# How to create a + inside a circle and changed to - on hover with css only

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to create with css only a + inside a circle with two more circles around and on hover to change the + to - and for some reason I can't make the +,- to appear on top of everything.

```
.icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 7;
 }
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/panoscool/pen/ZEOLdKY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a single element and a single pseudo You can draw the double border via `box-shadow` or `border: double Xpx;`

```css
b {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 1.2em;
  width: 1.2em;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: solid green 1px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; 
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.icoswap {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px white, 0 0 0 2px blue;
  background: crimson;
}

.icoswapbis {
  border: double 3px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, red) green;
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

b:before {
  content: '+';
}

b:hover:before {
  content: '';
  border-top: solid 0.125em;
  width: 0.5em
}
```

```html
<b class="icoswap"></b>
<b class="icoswapbis"></b>
```